# Crystal reports , the report you requested requires further information, login using ODBC DSN

Tags: crystal-reports, odbc, dsn

The report is runnig fine in Visual Studio 2005 but fails when I deploy it on IIS. It prompts, the report you requested requires further information. I think it needs to get installed some service pack either of SQL server client, or of Crystal Reports. Please suggest.

Comment: I have already developed reports I cannot change it now. Please suggest some other solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set data source of your report by code at run time so your report don't need to connect to database.

```
CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
report.SetDataSource(dt);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```